# Crash in UITableView sending message to deallocated UIViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, crash, core-animation

I have been fighting with the following stack trace for the whole day. I'm unable to reproduce the issue but I know it happens for a large number of users (Crashlytics).

```
Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
EXC_BAD_ACCESS KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000000000010

Thread : Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
0  libobjc.A.dylib                0x0000000194187bd0 objc_msgSend + 16
1  UIKit                          0x000000018860639c -[UITableView _createPreparedCellForGlobalRow:withIndexPath:willDisplay:] + 544
2  UIKit                          0x00000001885fafc4 -[UITableView _updateVisibleCellsNow:isRecursive:] + 2360
3  UIKit                          0x00000001883f0c60 -[UITableView layoutSubviews] + 172
4  UIKit                          0x000000018830d874 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 572
5  QuartzCore                     0x0000000187c65d58 -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 168
6  QuartzCore                     0x0000000187c60944 CA::Layer::layout_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 320
7  QuartzCore                     0x0000000187c607e8 CA::Layer::layout_and_display_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 32
8  QuartzCore                     0x0000000187c5ffe8 CA::Context::commit_transaction(CA::Transaction*) + 276
9  QuartzCore                     0x0000000187c5fd6c CA::Transaction::commit() + 436
10 UIKit                          0x0000000188304848 _afterCACommitHandler + 156
11 CoreFoundation                 0x0000000183b46388 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 32
12 CoreFoundation                 0x0000000183b43314 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 360
13 CoreFoundation                 0x0000000183b436f4 __CFRunLoopRun + 836
```

...

This happens in a UIViewController who owns a UITableView. The view controller is also the data source and the delegate for the table view.

Looking at the stack trace, I was guessing that the view controller would be deallocated while some animation or slow operation was going on. After trying everything, I can't find a configuration where this would happen.

Would you have any suggestion on why a VC could be deallocated while one of its view is still animating?

Comment: Can you verify that your theory is correct by adding an NSLog statement to your the dealloc method of your UIViewController?

Comment: I could but as I mentioned I cannot reproduce the issue, and I would need to go through the whole cycle of publishing a new update for that. Ideally I'd fix it before :)

Comment: I'm actually just noticing that this crash coincides with switching from UITableViewController to UIViewController + UITableView. Presumably, UITableViewController is nillifying the delegates and datasources. I think nillifying them will solve the issue. However, do you know when the delegate could be called when the controller has been destroyed?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I noticed that this crash coincides with switching from `UITableViewController` to `UIViewController` + `UITableView`.

Presumably, the `UITableViewController` was nillifying the table view's delegate and datasource when it was deallocated. It wasn't the case with the new code.

To solve the issue, I set them to nil in `- (void)dealloc`:

```
- (void)dealloc {
    _tableView.dataSource = nil;
    _tableView.delegate = nil;
}
```

The reason why they need to be set to nil is that [both the UITableView's dataSource and delegate are unsafe_unretained references](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uitableview_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UITableView/dataSource).

Comment: Thanks, this was very helpful. I am wondering how I could miss that part about assign i.e. unsafe_unretained ownership declaration of both .delegate and .dataSource properties of UITableView. I have always been thinking it was weak sort of declaration.

Comment: Many thanks for sharing your solution, this one has bugged me for a long time!

Comment: It turns-out that this is related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9963677/uitableview-crash-during-animation-fixing-solution-found-but-doesnt-locate-roo